# Floating point exception in C++ Trie

Tags: c++

The following code for Trie implementation is throwing Floating point exception upon call to function insert. The line inside for loop to check for existing node is where the problem is.

```
struct Node {
    char c;
    bool isend;
    unordered_map<int, struct Node*> map;
};

void insert(struct Node* root, string contact) {
    int size = contact.size();
    char ch;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ch = contact[i];
        // this check is creating problem
        if (root->map.find(ch) == root->map.end()) {
            struct Node* tmp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            tmp->c = ch;

            if (i == (size - 1)) {
                tmp->isend = true;
            } else {
                tmp->isend = false;
            }

            root->map.insert(make_pair(ch, tmp));
            root = tmp;            
       } else {
          root = root->map[ch];   
        }         

    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* root = NULL;

    root = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    insert(root, "text");
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, and then locate the exact line in your code? Please do that first.

Comment: Are you sure you got a floating point exception with this code ? There are no floating points used anywhere in it.

Comment: Oh and stop using old C code with C++ (like `malloc`). C++ is *not* "C with classes". Please [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and learn C++ properly.

Comment: Use of `malloc` in standard C++ is unusual. Unless you are a library implementer.

Comment: Despite what the error popup said, this code is not throwing a floating-point exception. Something went wrong, and the OS is guessing at the problem. Memory corruption often ends up being reported as a "floating-point exception", even though it has nothing to do with floating-point and nothing was thrown. So treat that error message as "something is broken"; nothing more.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe when the `unordered_map` needs to do a hash, some modulus operation gets all fouled up due to the map being bogus.

Comment: I forgot that [SIGFPE actually covers all arithmetic errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGFPE), so this could have been a simple division by 0 eg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `malloc` you are not invoking your `Node` class constructor, you are just allocating memory.

Use `new` instead which will both allocate the memory **and** call a constructor. So:

```
struct Node* tmp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

should be:

```
Node* tmp = new Node();
```

and:

```
struct Node* root = NULL;
root = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

should be:

```
Node* root = new Node();
```

Remember to `delete` where appropriate. Or even better, use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). 
And above all avoid using *C with classes*. Use proper standard C++.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use malloc in C++ code (unless you really know what you are doing)

```
root = new Node;
```

and

```
tmp = new Node;
```

The problem is that because you use malloc the constructor for `Node::map` is not getting called. Using `new` will make sure that all necessary constructors are called.

Comment: The (implicit) constructor for Node calls the Node::map constructor.

Comment: Thanks John I appreciate your help. It solved the issue.